# Python / Kivy - kv file calling does not work

Tags: python, kivy

I am building a life counter with Python and Kivy.

Below the code of my kv

```
#:kivy 1.0

<Test>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                BoxLayout: 
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: 50
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: "Life Counter"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: "Player 1"
                        Button:
                            text: "Player 2"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: "-"
                        Button:
                            text: "0"
                        Button:
                            text: "+"       
                        Button:
                            text: "-"
                        Button:
                            text: "0"
                        Button:
                            text: "+"
```

And here is my app

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App

class TestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Here is my output

[image]

Could you please help me understanding what I am missing?
If I add a simple Button with a description in the kv files the code works perfectly.
Thank you

Comment: Delete `<Test>:` line in your .kv and re-indent.

Comment: It works.. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved thanks to @FJSevilla removing `<test>` and re-indenting.

Answer (score 1):

the reason that your original code was not displaying anything is because in your main.py you created the class TestApp() and then you call it to run, but in your kv file you have `<Test>:` and everything is defined under that. basically all you had to do was create a new class like below:

```
class Test(AnchorLayout):
    pass
```

then in your TestApp class change to following:

```
class TestApp(App):
    define build(self):
    return Test()
```

remove test and anchorlayout from .kv and replace with the name of the new class "Test", and unindent the rest of the .kv file so everything is aligned.